# Concurrent access to same file using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, desktop-application

I have a desktop java application that can be run by different users. It makes use of JPA to access a database that is stored as a file. For this purpose I do not want to run a separate database server.

The purpose of the database is to store actions that are done in the program, it's a simple "store record" operation. But all users must be able to read these stored records.

How can I make sure the different applications can save their actions, while not overwriting the actions of the other? So I need a way to:

1. Open the database (file)
2. Lock it
3. Write the added action
4. Close the database (file)

Is there a way in JPA to do/enforce this ? I'm now using hibernate, but that's not a strict requirement.

Please do not answer with "you can do this with technology XXX". Please note that I'm concerned with respect to the concurrency issues and how to enforce that the file is opened, and closed again. How can this be done with technology XXX ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use SQLite database file. In this case, you can achieve concurrent access to the same file (e.g. database), and in the same time you can use [SQLite JDBC driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) along with your JPA provider (e.g. Hibernate).

The only disadvantage might be is that, strictly saying, it's not pure Java approach, as proposed JDBC driver has native libraries bundled there, but I wouldn't consider this as an issue.

Comment: I'm now using: property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver". To be honest I'm not really concerned whether something is a true java approach.

Comment: HSQLDB allows you to use file as DB-storage. But it has the restriction: if you use several application instances, which are using the same file, AFAIK it doesn't properly supports concurrent file access. Meanwhile SQLite does.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem I now have is that I cannot get Hibernate to work with SQLite. I get the following message: "Unable to determine Dialect to use [name=SQLite, majorVersion=3]; user must register resolver or explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'" . I think I should ask this in a separate question as it's difficult to find documentation how to fill in my persistence-unit.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't officially support SQLite Dialect, please check this resource http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/

Comment: Ah, so it's better to switch to EclipseLink or some other JPA provider in combination with SQLite?

Comment: Actually, it's up to you ;) But EclipseLink seems to be faster along with SQLite and it officially supports it

Comment: In the end, I just implemented a simple file reader/writer, removing all JPA related code. This reduces complexity the most as the code must be maintainable by other developers. However, I accept this answer as comes close to the original idea I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is an ORM (Object-relational Mapping) specification ; the R in ORM means the same thing than the R in RDBMS. JPA is so absolutely not suitable for flat file persistence systems

Comment: Whether is suitable is one thing, whether it can be used is another. I can always just take a file-oriented approach, but this would require removing/changing the JPA bindings/code that's already there now. Using a file-oriented approach requires me to write code (like reading/writing to file) that's already in some JPA implementations.

Comment: There is something I must misunderstand

Comment: [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) and [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) are examples of full-featured RDBMS with file storage without actual server (though HSQLDB has `in-memory` and server implementations also, but it's not the point).

Comment: Well ok with that but they fully implement SQL spec and so properly manage concurrent connections